# Unable to get the list of elements to select a text from the auto-complete text box using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am trying to enter a keyword to an auto-select box and select the specific text that I'm passing from the populated list.

```
Keyword: text_customer
Text needed to select: Constants.INBOUNDORDER_CUSTOMER
```

So far, the keyword is written in the auto-complete text box and the list is populated. Currently, I'm unable to get the list of elements as I'm struggling to find a unique element. ID is dynamic.

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(text_customer);
            List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class*= 'mat-autocomplete-panel ng-star-inserted mat-autocomplete-visible']"));
            for(WebElement option1: options){
            if(Constants.INBOUNDORDER_CUSTOMER.equals(option1.getText().trim()))
                option1.click();
                break;
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the element with text as **Constants.INBOUNDORDER_CUSTOMER** as the element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following *Locator Strategies*:

```
List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class= 'mat-autocomplete-panel ng-star-inserted mat-autocomplete-visible']//mat-option[contains(@class, 'mat-option')]"));
for(WebElement option: options){
    if (option1.getText().contains("INBOUNDORDER_CUSTOMER"))
        option1.click();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

To gather the items for your list it looks like you don't need to be specific. Try something like this:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(//*[contains(@id,"mat-option-")]));
```

That will populate your options List with all the elements that have an `ID` that contains `mat-option-`